# How can i modify duration days with resourceTimelineWeek header

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

i using resourceTimelinePlugin, and always it displayed 7 days in the header, i need change that, how can i do that?
[my calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQkq6.png)

my calendarOptions json:

```
calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
plugins: [resourceTimelinePlugin, interactionPlugin, momentPlugin],
schedulerLicenseKey: ConstanteCalendario.schedulerLicenseKey,
headerToolbar: {
  left: "today prev,next",
  center: "title",
  right: "",
},
initialView: OpcionVistaCalendarioEnum.LineaTiempoRecursoSemana,
slotLabelFormat: [
  { weekday: "short", day: "2-digit" }, // lower level of text
],
firstDay: moment().day(),
resourceAreaColumns: [
  {
    field: "nombreJuez",
    headerContent: "Jueces",
  },
],
editable: true,
selectable: true,
unselectAuto: true,
slotDuration: { days: 1 },
droppable: true,
locale: "es",
views: {
  resourceTimelinePlugin: {
    type: 'timelineWeek',
  },
  week: {
    titleFormat: { year: "numeric", month: "long", day: "2-digit" },
    titleRangeSeparator: " hasta ",
  },
},
timeZone: ConstanteCalendario.timeZone,
displayEventTime: false,
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the duration of a custom view using 'duration', see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/duration.
For instance, if you want to set up a separate view which allows you to view more days you can do that using https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/timeline-view.
e.g.

```
type: 'resourceTimeline',
duration: { days: 3 },
buttonText: '3 days'
```

Comment: i test that duration property in my calendar option json, but not work, keep show 7 days, the duration keep same.. and i cant find the option what i need anywhere.

Comment: Are you sure you're using a proper view? Your >resourceTimelinePlugin does not show up here in the docs, see '@fullcalendar/resource-timeline' at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/plugin-index